# php email insert break after mysql array

Tags: php, mysql, email

I have successfully pulled data from mySql into the message of the html email.  But after several attempts, I'm unable to add a two break lines after the 10th record.  Any assistance would be wonderful.

```
$sorc325sql = "Select * ".$sorc325sql2;
echo "<br>325sql=".$sorc325sql."<br><br>";
$sorc325res = mysqli_query($connectXXX, $sorc325sql) or die(mysqli_error($connectXXX));
if  (mysqli_num_rows($sorc325res) < 1) {
        $display_block = "<p><em>No topics exist.</em></p>";
    } else {
        while ($sorc325row = mysqli_fetch_array($sorc325res)) {
          $sorc325arycustctr++;
          $message .= $sorc325row['progName'].', ';
          }
    }
```

Comment: `if (!($rows++ % 10)) { echo "\n"; }`

Comment: Hi Marc, thanks for quick response but didn't work.  Here is what I tried                                                                                                    $message .= $sorc325row['progName'].', ';                                                                                                          if (!($sorc325row++ % 10)) { $message .='<br><br>'; }

          }
    }

Comment: You should edit your comment into the question so we can clearly see what the code looks like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `Mark B`'s idea, you need to add it to the current `$sorc325arycustctr++;` line

```
$sorc325sql = "Select * ".$sorc325sql2;
echo "<br>325sql=".$sorc325sql."<br><br>";
$sorc325res = mysqli_query($connectXXX, $sorc325sql) 
                   or die(mysqli_error($connectXXX));

if  (mysqli_num_rows($sorc325res) < 1) {
    $display_block = "<p><em>No topics exist.</em></p>";
} else {

    $sorc325arycustctr = 0;

    while ($sorc325row = mysqli_fetch_array($sorc325res)) {
       $sorc325arycustctr++;
       if (! ($sorc325arycustctr % 10)) {
           $message .= '<br>'; 
       }
       $message .= $sorc325row['progName'].', ';
    }
}
```

Comment: Didn't work.  BTW, this is email and so I replaced echo with message.=  The code is adding a break to each record.

Comment: Sorry, fixed that woops in my answer, maybe it because the `$sorc325arycustctr` was not initialized to zero

Comment: Silly me, ok fixed, completely missed the notting `!`